# Rails web-push throws an error 401 (unauthorized)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-push

I'm getting a 
`{"code": 401, "errno": 109, "error": "Unauthorized", "more_info": "http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes", "message": "Request did not validate missing authorization header"}` error in my rails app. But it was working just fine until yesterday...

This is the code for the `payload_send`

```rb
Webpush.payload_send(
      endpoint: s[:endpoint],
      p256dh: s[:p256dh],
      auth: s[:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: vapid_keys[:subject],
        public_key: vapid_keys[:public_key],
        private_key: vapid_keys[:private_key]
      }
)
```

And all the required parameters are definitely completely filled in.

I'm using this webpush library for rails https://github.com/zaru/webpush

Comment: missing of authorization header. you are not passing authorization key or whatever needed to authorize user.

Comment: a 401 response might also come because of wrong parameter values. Do check the keys that you are sending in the payload are valid.